# PHP download file issue

Tags: php, image, ftp, download

```
<?php

// sample usage
ini_set('max_execution_time', 6000);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

$local_file = '123.jpg';
$server_file = '/animals/pets/dogs/pitbull.jpg';
$ftp_user_name='username';
$ftp_user_pass='password';
$ftp_server='URL';
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);


ftp_set_option($conn_id, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 60);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, false);
// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)){
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

The above code is not downloading the file. **What could be the issue with downloading the file?**

Comment: What is the output you get ?

Comment: What indication do you have that there's a problem?  Is there an error?  Unexpected behavior?  What is the request to the server?  What is the response from the server?  You need to do at least *some* debugging.

Comment: `/photos/bigphoto/529/509529_01.jpg` is a absolute path, are you sure you don't want to use relative paths

Comment: Do you have any errors??

Comment: Check your apache logs

Comment: I am getting output of the else block. Indication is file not downloaded. There was a warning message like `Warning: ftp_get(): Command not implemented in line 22`. Not sure what a request of the server. Not sure whether I have to use absolute or relative path. Is relative path something which can directly show up the image in a browser?

Comment: As Jompper mentioned, instead of an absolute path use a relative path. If your `animals` folder is one up from your root where you're running your script, use `$server_file = 'animals/pets/dogs/pitbull.jpg';` @BannedfromSO --- An absolute path would resemble something like `$server_file = '/var/user/you/public_html/animals/pets/dogs/pitbull.jpg';`

Comment: one up means after `wwwroot`?

Comment: Probably. I don't know what your server's setup is. As I mentioned, if you're running this code from your root, then use what I wrote. For example (root being your public_html folder) `root/your_script.php/animals/pets/dogs/pitbull.jpg` @BannedfromSO

Comment: Fred why don't you post it as an answer so that I can accept it. It's working for me mate!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked out. Kudos to Jompper @BannedfromSO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jompper [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334872/php-download-file-issue/21335680#comment32162078_21334872), instead of an absolute path use a relative path.
If your animals folder is one up from your root where you're running your script,

use

```
$server_file = 'animals/pets/dogs/pitbull.jpg';
```

An absolute path would resemble something like

```
$server_file = '/var/user/you/public_html/animals/pets/dogs/pitbull.jpg';
```

As I mentioned, if you're running this code from your root, then use what I wrote.

For example

(root being your public_html folder)

```
root/your_script.php/animals/pets/dogs/pitbull.jpg
```

Comment: What if in the case if I wanted to download a file from a web service, which has blocked exposing or images being shown up on the browser? and also we don't the path like `public_html/animals/pets/dogs/pitbull.jpg` but `ftp://domain.com/images/photos/image.jpg, Please answer because this is the real work.

Comment: I think you may need to use Curl for that. I don't know enough about it to write code for it, but am pretty sure that's what you'll need to use. As for the `public_html...` issue, that shouldn't be a problem if you're concerned about security issues. @BannedfromSO